# ActionScript 2: Why is class variable lost when using an event?

Tags: actionscript-2

Can anyone explain to me why this failed and how to get it to work?

**NOTE:** This is ActionScript 2, so ActionScript 3 responses will probably not help.

For this example create a movieclip on the stage that has the label "test_mc".

Frame 1:

```
import mcClicker;

var test = new mcClicker(test_mc);
```

mcClicker.as:

```
class mcClicker{
    public var obj;

    private function objPress(){
        trace(obj); //<--- This fails
    }

    public function mcClicker(the_obj){
        obj = the_obj;
        obj.onPress = objPress;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a long time since I've had to use ActionScript 2.0, but I think this is probably a case for Delegate which will allow you to call the objPress function with the clicker instance as the scope - see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000233.html

Comment: It seems like that works, but then I lose the ability to use the "this" keyword within the onPress function.

Comment: This should be the scope you've specified as the first param of the create method. So if you do this: obj.onPress = Delegate.create(this, this.objPress). This should refer to the instance of the class mcClicker which is what I think you want.

Comment: I found out that I could also do something like this: var scope = this; obj.onPress = function(){scope.objPress();}; It still changes the "this" keyword to now reference the class instead of the object that the event occurred on.

Comment: I prefer the delegate syntax personally but go with whatever you're most comfortable with. :)